# Do I qualify for a personal 401-K Plan?

Tags: united-states, contractor, solo-401k

I was wondering if anyone could tell me if I qualify to set up a personal 401-k Plan?  I am currently employed and make a full salary.  I have maxed out my individual contribution in my personal IRA account at $5500 this year.

I also receive income as an independent contractor both from my current employer with a 1099-Misc for work that I do above and beyond my regular employment contract and also as compensation for new clients that I bring into the firm.  I also get paid directly from some clients.  I have my own private business account and personal EIN number for the contractor work.

My employer doesn't offer any 401-K or pension plan and I feel I'm behind in the retirement game.  I would really like to start using some of the money I'm earning as an independent contractor (no employees) to save in a personal 401-K.  Am I eligible?  I can't get a straight answer from anyone on this.  I believe that I am.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is my understanding that if you are a W2 employee with a company other than your own, you are not eligible for a self 401k. You should probably look at using a taxable brokerage account instead for additional retirement savings.

Comment: It's my understanding that he's both a W2 employee and an independent contractor. Being the former doesn't prevent him from being the latter.

Comment: David is correct.  I am both a W2 employee and an independent contractor.  I understand that the W2 income cannot be used for a personal 401K but I believe that I can use the independent contractor money?  J

Comment: @Derek that's correct

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a tax lawyer, but from what I can tell it looks like you'd be eligible to use your contractor income to fund a Solo 401(k).  http://www.irafinancialgroup.com/whatissolo401k.php
"To access these benefits an investor must meet two eligibility requirements:

1. The presence of self employment activity.
2. The absence of full-time employees."

And from the IRS itself (http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-tege/forum08_401k.pdf)